# Failed to create Browser Error (Access denied)

Tags: wpf, dotnetbrowser

I'm getting "Failed to create Browser" error when using multiple instances of my app.
I use different folders for each instance as advised.

Error:
Failed to create Browser.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessTimes()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StartTime()
   at ⁬‪⁪‍⁬‫‍‫‬‎‫‬‭⁯‭‎⁪⁯‌‭‭⁮‮⁪‎⁪​⁯​‪‭‍‎⁯⁫‏‫‬‬⁬‮.‍⁭‪​‪⁬⁫⁪‪‬‌​⁭‎⁫‪‎‬⁮⁭‍‬‬‌⁭⁯⁪⁫‍⁫‎‮⁮‌⁭⁪⁪‎‎‭‮(Int32 )
   at ​‏‪⁪‍‫‭⁮⁯‮⁪‌‬‏‫⁬‫‭⁪⁪‭⁮​⁭‍⁪⁯‫‭⁮⁯‌⁫⁮‭‬⁭‌‍⁬‮.‌⁭⁮‭‮‫⁬⁬⁭⁬⁬⁪​‏‎⁯‪‪⁭⁮‫‬​⁯⁭‭⁪⁮‬‪⁬‮‏⁮⁬‭‏⁫⁯‮‮()
   at ⁬‪⁮⁭‬⁭​‭‎⁯​⁫​⁯‬⁬‫‫⁭⁫‭‬⁫‍⁫‪‬‏⁫​⁭‭‌⁭‌‮‪⁮‫⁯‮..ctor(‍‏‭‬‏‎⁮‍⁬‭‮‫‮⁫‭‬⁯‪⁫⁬⁫‭⁮‎⁪‪​‌​‪‌⁭‭‫‏‌⁯⁯⁬‍‮ , BrowserType )
   at ‍⁭‎⁯​‫⁬‬‬‪​⁭‭‪⁪⁭⁬⁫‪‬‍‪‬‭⁫⁬‭‪‏‪⁬‎‭⁫⁫‎⁫‍‫‬‮.‏‌‏⁯⁪‬‎‬‌⁬‭‎‎⁯⁫⁬‫⁬‎​⁬‌‬‪⁭‬⁫‮‎‫⁪‏‌‎‌‌⁪‏‌‏‮(⁬‍‮⁯​⁯⁮⁬⁮​⁮‍⁮‮⁫⁯‎‭⁪⁪‌⁮‌‏‍⁫⁮‪‭‎⁬‫⁬‫‪⁭⁫⁮‮⁮‮ , BrowserContext , BrowserType )
   at ‍⁭‎⁯​‫⁬‬‬‪​⁭‭‪⁪⁭⁬⁫‪‬‍‪‬‭⁫⁬‭‪‏‪⁬‎‭⁫⁫‎⁫‍‫‬‮.‏‌‏⁯⁪‬‎‬‌⁬‭‎‎⁯⁫⁬‫⁬‎​⁬‌‬‪⁭‬⁫‮‎‫⁪‏‌‎‌‌⁪‏‌‏‮(BrowserContext , Int32 , BrowserType )
   at DotNetBrowser.BrowserFactory.Create(BrowserContext browserContext, BrowserType browserType)
   at DotNetBrowser.BrowserFactory.Create(BrowserContext browserContext, BrowserType browserType)
   at DotNetBrowser.BrowserFactory.Create(BrowserContext browserContext)

My code:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Args[0] == "brow1") Test.MainWindow.browserCtx = "brow1")
        else if (e.Args[0] == "brow2") Test.MainWindow.browserCtx = "brow2")
        else Test.MainWindow.browserCtx = "brow3") 

        Test.MainWindow.site = e.Args[1];
    }

programPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
BrowserPreferences.SandboxEnabled = true;
BrowserPreferences.ChromiumDirName = programPath + "Browser";
BrowserPreferences.CrashDumpDir = programPath + "Browser\\CrashDump\\";

browser = BrowserFactory.Create(new BrowserContext(new BrowserContextParams(programPath + "Browser\\Cache\\" + browserCtx)));

webView = new WPFBrowserView(browser);

var defaulDialogtHandler = webView.Browser.DialogHandler;
webView.Browser.DialogHandler = new CustomDialogHandler(defaulDialogtHandler);    

webView.Browser.PopupHandler = new CustomPopupHandler(webView);
webView.Browser.LoadHandler = new CustomLoadHandler();
browser.ContextMenuHandler = new CustomMenuHandler((FrameworkElement)webView, true);
browser.Preferences.WebRTCIPHandlingPolicy = BrowserPreferences.WebRTCIPHandlingPolicyEnum.DisableNonProxiedUdp;

mainLayout.Children.Add(webView);

browser.Preferences.AllowDisplayingInsecureContent = true;
browser.Preferences.FireKeyboardEventsEnabled = false;
browser.Preferences.FireMouseEventsEnabled = false;        
browser.Preferences.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
browser.Preferences.JavaScriptCanAccessClipboard = false;   
browser.Preferences.LocalStorageEnabled = true;         
browser.Preferences.PluginsEnabled = true;  
browser.Preferences.WebAudioEnabled = false; 

browser.FinishLoadingFrameEvent += Browser_FinishLoadingFrameEvent;    

browser.LoadURL(site);
```

Comment: Could you please provide the DotNetBrowser logging? Here is the link how to enable it: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110288-logging

Comment: I enabled logging and solved the problem, it was a SQLite error (database is locked). I believe that I killed the process at one point when the browser was accessing the cache/history database and the the browser was not properly disposed so the database remained locked. I deleted the cache folder and now it works.)
Error https://pastebin.com/nJeDVbd5

Comment: @Cœur thank you for the link. I read it.